# How to create a part in Eagle that consists of multiple other symbols? (with elements that share the same pin)

Tags: integrated-circuit, eaglecad, pins

I'm trying to create an Eagle part for an IC which is an array of 5 matched transistors (eg CA3046/CA3086/AS3046D).

Two of the transistors are a differential pair that share the same IC pin (pin3).

I'm familiar with adding multiple symbols to the package, but Eagle isn't allowing me to add the 5th transistor symbol because it exceeds the total pin count (SOIC-14)...

How is this handled?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple symbol pins map to a single footprint pad in Eagle.

What you could do is make a symbol for the two transistors which share a pin and add that to your device instead of two individual transistor symbols.

Comment: Many thanks, I've done that and it's working. I'm copying a vintage schematic and it only shows one transistor symbol but is labelled 1,2,3 to one of the pins to represent the second half of the pair. I've just wired accordingly.